# Point at infinity symbol?

Tags: pdftex, symbols

guys very simple question here.  I'm writing a paper on elliptic curves, and the domain of the function has this extra point which is referred to as "a point at infinity."

It looks like this :[image: Point at infinity]

I have no clue what the shortcut is for that.  I've just been using the letter O instead.  Anyone know what that symbol is?  Appreciate the help!

Comment: I mean, it's not really a shortcut, but a command: `\mathcal{O}` (requires the `amssymb` package)